# Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

Tags: ios4

I get an error in the iphone SDK:

> Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Check out your provisioning profile credentials and may be your developer certificate will not ok. so revoke it using CSR and download new provisioning profile. make build and upload it through application loader.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are selecting yourapplicationname.app for iphoneos/ipados (build/Release-iphoneos).

(I had compressed and submitted the iphonesimulator's app in build/Release-iphonesimulator which caused this error.)